# PC keep freezing, how to lookup the last error

Tags: windows-10, freeze, hardware-failure, windows-error-reporting

my PC with windows 10 keep freezing at what looks like random times, the mouse stop moving and ctrl+alt+canc has no effect, I have to shut it down via power button. I have run BurnInTest and it found no errors.

How can I lookup the last error, the cause that makes it freeze all of a sudden? I'm not playing games nor watching videos of sort, just using the browser or LibreOffice or File Explorer. No particular app open at the moment of the freeze.

Comment: Try safe mode, run `sfc.exe /scannow` and `chkdsk`

Answer (score 0):

Reboot the machine and press F8 just after power and BIOS screen to get Windows boot options. Select safe mode to start with only necessary services for diagnosis. Then once in Windows search for control panel, administrative tools, Event viewer. Each log informs of different system areas, system log has many fault codes which can be copied and looked up online.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can I access the event log only in safe mode?

Comment: I have opened Event Viewer but it only says that I shut down the PC using unconventional way (power button) but not the reason that made it crash.

Comment: Windows will not present you with an obvious reason always. You have to look at the error messages with red crosses around the time of the crash in System and Application log. You should be able to do detective work to find an error code for the time of the crash.